# How do I move file under source control to another folder using Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

> I want to move a file to a different folder under source control (Azure DevOps repos not TFS)

I have a project (VS 2019) under source control DevOps repos. I want to reorganise some items and created a new folder. How do I move existing files under source control to the new folder without losing the change history. If I try to move it from VS Solution Explorer, it is creating as a new file. 
Some posts suggested that it can be done using Visual Studio source control explorer , but I cannot find that for AzureDevOps in VS 2019.
I have also tried doing it on AzureDevOps web, no such option that I can find to move files to different path.

I'm using Git as source control via Azure DevOps Repos and Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Are you using git as version control system in Azure Devops?

Comment: If you're using Git, be aware that there is no such thing as "file history" in Git. There are only commits: the commits *are* the history. No commit goes away, so renaming or moving a file does not change history. Adding commits adds more history. Some commands, such as `git log -- <path>`, show you *stripped down* history by deliberately failing to mention commits that don't have changed to the specified path, and that path is that path, so if you want multiple paths including the *old* name, you have to list the old name too.

Comment: Git *does* have `git log --follow`, which is a horrible hack that tries to automatically follow renames for *one* path, and does work fairly well for the usual cases. But it works by the same mechanism as `git log -- <path>`, it's just that it detects renames and *changes which path it is using for filtering* as it goes.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Git as source control (Azure DevOps repo).

Comment: @torek Thanks for your reply. I was a bit surprised the change history is retained even after I moved it to another folder and Committed as a new file. (it first showed a + sign which means it's going to be a new addition to Git).. Is Git does it by the file name across any folder?

Comment: @torek Update: now folder structure shows correctly in Visual Studio, but nothing changed on Git. i.e. it is still under old folder, not moved to the new folder.

Comment: Git merely stores a *full snapshot of every file* in every commit. So before you move a file from `path/to/file` to `new/path/file`, the old commit has a file named `path/to/file`. After you move that file, the new commit has a file named `new/path/file`. The *content* is a duplicate, and Git de-duplicates files: it would do that if you *copied* the file too. Later, some, but not all, Git commands will sometimes look for renamed and/or copied files by comparing the *content*.

Comment: Note that Git does not store folders! Instead, each commit has a file with forward slashes in the name. If your OS (Windows) uses backwards slashes in your working tree, Git accommodates your OS as needed here. Git *builds* folders-and-files in your working tree as required by your OS, but *stores* just the files, with the slashes in the names. (Technically this is not 100% right: the forward slash names are in Git's *index* rather than in the commits. But it works out the same.)

Comment: @torek thanks for taking time to help. It makes much mores sense now.